# Table view's cell.selectedBackgroundView briefly visible when returning to table view

Tags: ios

I've implemented a table view following Matt Gallagher's Cocoa With Love tutorial (http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) and when a table cell is selected by the user a view controller with a UIWebView is pushed to the table view controller's stack.

When the user selects a row, then after returning back to the table view from the UIWebView the selected cell image displays briefly (maybe 1/5 of a second) before the table view is displayed normally.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you deselect the cell before switching to the next controller ? 
You can do that by using this method of the UITableView :

```
- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated
```